# @group and @override in CSS?

Tags: css

I've seen this in a stylesheet and I was wondering if it actually does anything and if so, what does it do? Google doesn't seem to be helpful for me on this one. I've removed the url from the code but I was curious if this actually did anything. I see that it's commented out but I'm just curious. Is it strictly a stylistic thing to help the designer?

```
/* @override 
    <url of stylsheet>
*/

/* @group Colors */

/* Orange - ff7800 */
/* Gray Blue - 373d4a */

/* @end */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @frank mentioned, **/* @group */** and **/* @end */** are meta data used by Espresso. Below is a screen capture of this meta data in action.  Folders are created in the Navigator on the right of the window.

[image: Espresso With CSS Navigator]

If you are using VI then you can add the following comment in the CSS file to create folds for quick navigation.

```
/*
 vim: set foldmethod=marker:
 vim: set foldmarker=@group,@end:
 vim: set nofoldenable:
*/
```

If you are unfamiliar with vim folds some of the key combos are:

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> - Close all folds

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - Open fold

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - Close fold

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - Toggle fold open/close

[image: VI folds in action]

Comment: `@override` is also an Espresso-only thing...it lets you override the stylesheet of a live page with your local stylesheet. That way you can preview how your stylesheet will affect the page without having to upload anything (very useful for styling dynamic pages).

Answer (score 3):

Those are meta tags used by the HTML/CSS editor [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) (formerly known as CSSEdit).

Answer (score 1):

Those look like some editor meta tags. I'd guess `@group` is the same as `#region` in visual studio and `@override` links another css file for something like intellisense, but I haven't seen any editor supporting this, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Anything inside of these things,

```
/*
  Foo...
*/
```

is a comment. It's not read or interpreted by any browser, so it has absolutely no impact upon the rendering of the webpage.

My guess is that this code,

```
/* @group Colors */

/* Orange - ff7800 */
/* Gray Blue - 373d4a */

/* @end */
```

could be used by a CSS-generating interpreter, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), when it outputs its final CSS.

Just a guess...

Comment: In my question, I stated that I knew what a comment was. :)

Comment: Just ignore mah first paragraph, then ;)

Comment: Where did you get this file, might I ask? Maybe it has some more comments.

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out already, `@group` is just a way to segment or group your CSS.

CSS Edit will put all of the CSS in a nice folder in your sidebar navigation so you can easily navigate through large CSS files.

I find it handy when I am converting some site that has many CSS files, and I want to put all of their CSS into a single file.

I'll use `@group` to segment CSS from each of the original site's files ... one `@group` for each.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are only comments for whoever is editing the CSS file. It'll have no impact on the layout or functionality.